# SQL trigger that checks two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I've been given a project to create several triggers. This is the last in a series.  "Create a trigger that insures that the job code in the EMPLOYEE table is a valid job code from the job table." Clearly referencing two tables.

Can I use following simple code to accomplish? Can two tables be used simultaneously for a trigger on tables?

```
CREATE TRIGGER valJobCode
ON EMPLOYEE
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS 
    BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE
    ADD CHECK(SELECT EMPLOYEE.JOB_CODE, JOB.JOB_CODE
              FROM EMPLOYEE INNER JOIN JOB ON 
              EMPLOYEE.JOB_CODE=JOB.JOB_CODE
              WHERE (EMPLOYEE.JOB_CODE >=500 AND EMPLOYEE.JOB_CODE <= 510)
END
```

Comment: Look into using a *foreign key constraint* for the first part of your requirement, and a *check constraint* for the second part.  There is no need for a trigger that I can see.

Comment: On a side note: If both tables are in the same database then as matbailie has stated foreign key is the way to go. But if you are trying to create this kind of relationship between two table which happen to be in two different databases then you need triggers to implement this logic.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to ALTER a table to add a check in a trigger. That means that in every Insert, Update or Delete transaction you will trying to alter the table adding the same check.

If you have to use a trigger, then remove the `ALTER TABLE` and `ADD CHECK` instructions and just return `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` if your SELECT condition is true. Although you do not need a trigger to accomplish what a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on the employee.job_code columns should do.

Comment: I concur with what most will say is an unnecessary Trigger. I didn't think about the FK constraint. Because the project is to create a Trigger, the FK constraint is the best course of action.